# Nodejs v8.17 not updating on hyper ledger fabric

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am using Hyper ledger fabric and node v 8.17 have installed when i update the node from version 8.17 to version 12.0 it updated to version 12.0
but when i restart the terminal it goes back to version 8.17. How can i resolve this issue?[error shows v 8.17 no longer supported]

Comment: Which OS are you using and how did you install NodeJS?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the old Node binary with your target Node binary.

1. Download binary from the official [site](https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.1/node-v12.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz)
2. `tar -xvf node-v12.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz`
3. `sudo cp node-v12.18.1-linux-x64.tar.xz/bin/node $(where node)`
4. `node --version` should display the new version now.